# Greasemonkey script to alter youtube pages does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, onload

I wrote a Greasemonkey script to insert a script to YouTube page, and after the script is loaded, replace the text of the content("Download" to Japanese word (In this question, I will use "TEST" instead.)).

However, the script does not work in the way I want.

I wanted to insert this to the html;

> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/25105.user.js" onload="var elements=document.getElementsByClassName('yt-uix-button-content');for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)elements[i].innerHTML.replace('Download','TEST');"></script>

But actually inserted is this (onload="" is missing.);

> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/25105.user.js"></script>

What is the problem?

```
// Start script
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
if ((document.URL.match("www.youtube.com/watch?"))||(document.URL.match("c.youtube.com/videoplayback?"))) {
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/25105.user.js';
script.onload = "var elements=document.getElementsByClassName('yt-uix-button-content');for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)elements[i].innerHTML.replace('Download','TEST');"; //Not working
head.appendChild(script);
};},!1);
// End
```

Comment: Maybe it's already too late for `onload`? Try to call/run it directly.

Comment: Even if it is too late, at least 'onload=""' should be inserted to html. There must me a mistake in my script.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    if ((document.URL.match("www.youtube.com/watch?"))||(document.URL.match("c.youtube.com/videoplayback?"))) {
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/25105.user.js';

        if( script.readyState ) {
            script.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if( script.readyState == 'loaded' || scriptTag.readyState == 'complete' ) {
                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    scriptHandler();
                }
            };
        }
        else {
            script.onload = function() {
                scriptHandler();
            };
        }
        head.appendChild(script);
    }
},false);


function scriptHandler() {
    var scriptContent = document.createElement('script');
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    scriptContent.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptContent.text = "var elements=document.getElementsByClassName('yt-uix-button-content');for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)elements[i].innerHTML.replace('Download','TEST');";
    s.appendChild(scriptContent);
}
```